# Stream Large Upload videos from iOS to php server using AFNetworking

Tags: php, iphone, ios, objective-c

Hello everyone i need a little help .

I have to upload very big videos around 400-500 MBs maximum from an app I have been working on to a PHP server.

I tried sending them using base-64 encoding and uploading to PHP server.

It worked for files of small sizes but using it for big files was just a stupid attempt which hanged my simulator and nothing uploaded.

Now I tried using `AFNetworking` using `multipartFormRequestWithMethod` by setting `NSStream` but was not able to get it to work.

If somebody can please help by providing some example of how to do this along with a little PHP code for the server would be a great help.